# How to add an actionEvent that triggers a function defined elsewhere?

Tags: java, swing

I was working on Java adding a button that triggers a fuction when clicked. This is the GUI file that executes from the main class to make the window of the game. The only way to do it I found was this:

```
package Kingdomino;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
...

public class createAndShowGUI extends JPanel {

    static public JComboBox createNumPlayersMenu(){
        String[] lista = {"2 players","3 players","4 players"};
        JComboBox numPlayersMenu = new JComboBox(lista);
        numPlayersMenu.setSelectedIndex(2);
        numPlayersMenu.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,30));
        return numPlayersMenu;
    }

    static public JComboBox createPlayerColorMenu(){
        String[] lista = {"blue","green","red","pink"};
        JComboBox playerColor = new JComboBox(lista);
        playerColor.setSelectedIndex(2);
        playerColor.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,30));
        return playerColor;
    }   

    static public JButton createPlayButton()  {
        JButton createPlayButton = new JButton();
        createPlayButton.setText("Play");
        return createPlayButton;
    }

    static public void main() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Box verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();      
        jpanel.add(verticalBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Hi");
        verticalBox.add(label);

        Box horizontalBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        horizontalBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700,50));

        JComboBox numPlayersMenu = createNumPlayersMenu();
        horizontalBox.add(numPlayersMenu);

        JComboBox playerColor = createPlayerColorMenu();
        horizontalBox.add(playerColor);

        verticalBox.add(horizontalBox);

        JButton btnNewButton = createPlayButton();
        btnNewButton.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener() {          
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                String num1 =  numPlayersMenu.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String num2 = playerColor.getSelectedItem().toString();
                label.setText( "Selected number of players: "+num1 + " // selected color: " + num2 );
        }
        });
        verticalBox.add(btnNewButton);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The issue is that if the function that I wanted to implement was more complicated than a few lines of code, I would like to implement it in a different method, not inside the code of *main()*.

I have tried a lot of methods to try to do this but none worked. This method seemed the simplest and cleanest, but I dislike defining a function inside the main() method, I would rather have it outside and reference it inside the action listener.

I am sure there must be a way to do this but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: You've got too much code in static methods and no code that creates true OOP-compliant objects, as if you've created this program in a stream of consciousness way. Don't. Plan your classes before coding, so that they are well behaved objects, objects with states and behaviors and start over.

Comment: How would that help me solve my problem? Just genuinely asking, I don't see the need to do something that doesn't improve or solve my problems, and just makes the code more complicated. If it's actually useful I will do it.

Comment: That's just it, what *you're doing* is making your code needlessly complicated and non-functioning. So yes, you should scrap this code and start over. Again, stream-of-consciousness type code is not worth the effort.

Comment: For example, your posted code has no fields -- so how do you share state between methods (other than through parameters)? How does this state persist and change as the program runs?

Comment: Thanks for making a good chunk of comments that don't answer the question in any way.

Comment: I'm actually not trying to frustrate you and an trying to help you, seriously please believe me. You can ignore these comments, but if you don't your code *will* be better off for it. As for your specific problem, you need to show the *non-working* code so that myself and others have a better idea of exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Again my suggestions in comments may seem that I'm over-complicating things by suggesting that you re-think your code, that you strive to make it more object-oriented compliant, and in the short term this may be true, but in the medium and long-term the exact opposite is true, since right now your game is very simple, and you're just trying to set two properties, and int and a Color, but as soon as you make this just a little more complex, the complexities brought about by leaving everything in the static realm can become overwhelming.

So having said that, just what am I suggesting? First extract out the model (non-GUI state) from the view (GUI code), and here the model is very simple, a class that holds an int, and a Color, one that has a constructor, fields, getters/setters, and anything else needed, something like so:

```
import java.awt.Color;

// class that holds the non-GUI "state" of the game
// Also holds non-GUI behaviors as well via its methods
public class Game {
    // fields to hold state
    private int numberOfPlayers;
    private Color color;

    public Game() {
        this(0, Color.WHITE);
    }

    public Game(int numberOfPlayers, Color color) {
        this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
        return numberOfPlayers;
    }

    public void setNumberOfPlayers(int numberOfPlayers) {
        this.numberOfPlayers = numberOfPlayers;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // other behavior methods here
}
```

Then let's create a JPanel that holds and displays the two JComboBoxes, say called UserSelectionPanel:

```
public class UserSelectionPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS_ITEMS = {
            "2 Players", "3 Players", "4 Players"};

    // using "parallel arrays" below, not a good thing long-term
    private static final String[] COLOR_ITEMS = {
            "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Pink"
    };
    private static final Color[] COLORS = {
            Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.PINK
    };
    private static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    JComboBox<String> numberOfPlayersCombo = new JComboBox<>(NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS_ITEMS);
    JComboBox<String> colorsCombo = new JComboBox<>(COLOR_ITEMS);
```

We also can give this getter methods so we can extract what the user selects, for example the one for player number:

```
public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
    int selection = numberOfPlayersCombo.getSelectedIndex();
    if (selection < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return selection + 2;
    }
}
```

The whole thing could look like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserSelectionPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS_ITEMS = {
            "2 Players", "3 Players", "4 Players"};

    // using "parallel arrays" below, not a good thing long-term
    private static final String[] COLOR_ITEMS = {
            "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Pink"
    };
    private static final Color[] COLORS = {
            Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.PINK
    };
    private static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    JComboBox<String> numberOfPlayersCombo = new JComboBox<>(NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS_ITEMS);
    JComboBox<String> colorsCombo = new JComboBox<>(COLOR_ITEMS);

    public UserSelectionPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        add(new JLabel("Number of Players:"));
        add(numberOfPlayersCombo);
        add(new JLabel("Color:"));
        add(colorsCombo);
    }

    public Color getSelectedColor() {
        int selection = colorsCombo.getSelectedIndex();
        if (selection < 0) {
            return DEFAULT_COLOR;
        } else {
            return COLORS[selection];
        }
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
        int selection = numberOfPlayersCombo.getSelectedIndex();
        if (selection < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return selection + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

And then we could easily display this JPanel in a JOptionPane if we'd like to show it, and get information from it

Next a main JPanel that is displayed in the main JFrame that plays the game. Ours would at this point be very simple, just hold a JLabel that displays the number of players, a JButton that displayes the UserSelectionPanel within a JOptionPane, and the main JPanel's background color would reflect the selected color. We could also give it a Game object so that the Game object's state is updated when the user selection is made. Something like so:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainGamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 450;
    private UserSelectionPanel userSelectionPanel = new UserSelectionPanel();
    private Game game;
    private JLabel numberOfPlayersLabel = new JLabel("0");

    public MainGamePanel(Game game) {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setOpaque(false); // so color shows through

        // display the number of players here
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Number of Players:"));
        topPanel.add(numberOfPlayersLabel);

        // to hold button that displays dialog
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        middlePanel.setOpaque(false); // same reason
        middlePanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Set-Up Game") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setUpGameActionPerformed();
            }
        }));

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        this.game = game;
        setBackground(game.getColor());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(middlePanel);
    }

    private void setUpGameActionPerformed() {
        // set up the JOptionPane
        Component parentComponent = MainGamePanel.this;
        UserSelectionPanel message = userSelectionPanel; // *** our all-imporant JPanel
        String title = "Set-up Game";
        int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
        int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;

        // display the JOptionPane
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parentComponent, message, title,
                optionType, messageType);

        // if the user pressed "OK" then make the changes
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            // update the state of the GUI
            int numberOfPlayers = userSelectionPanel.getNumberOfPlayers();
            Color color = userSelectionPanel.getSelectedColor();

            // and update our Game field, game:
            game.setNumberOfPlayers(numberOfPlayers);
            game.setColor(color);

            numberOfPlayersLabel.setText(String.valueOf(numberOfPlayers));
            setBackground(color);
        }
    }
}
```

And we could run the whole thing like so:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGameMain {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Game game = new Game();
        MainGamePanel mainPanel = new MainGamePanel(game);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("OOP Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

So why go through all this mess? Because your current game set up is very simple, and as soon as you try to make it more complex and interesting, will be *very* difficult to debug and enhance. If you separate out concerns in this way, if you use OOPs to your advantage, you have a better chance of creating something that can grow and improve.

Comment: welp thanks, I will review that code and try to write it in a more "OOP way". I just don´t see the need so far to instatiate classes when I just need to run them once. That's why I just use static methods and objects, I don't need specific instances.

Comment: Question: I don`t get why just writting "add" instead of "topPanel.add" works. Shouldnt you specify  where you are adding the panels?